# How to specify a minimal required Java update in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I'm building a Java FX application which uses the `Dialog` classes added to Oracle JDK 1.8 in update 40. Therefore, the minimal required Java version is 1.8**u40**.

I now want to ensure this version requirement in my Gradle build file. Obviously, checking against the major version with

```java
assert org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current().isJava8Compatible()
```

does not help in this case as it omits the update number.

How do I specify this contraint in my build file?

Comment: The only idea that comes to my head is to read `System.properties['java.version']` and check if if starts with: *1.8.0_4*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account Opal's suggestion the following splits the version string and checks against the update number.

```java
if (javaVersion.startsWith("1.8.0") && javaVersion.split("_")[1].toInteger() < 40) {
    throw new GradleException("Java version 1.8.0_40 or later required, but was $javaVersion")
}
```